# Displaying image with PIL causes weird color patches

Tags: python, image, colors, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a pytorch model which outputs an image.
The problem is in displaying this image as the output is a torch tensor with values between 0-1.
If I display it like this it works fine

```
out=model.forward(x)
out=torch.squeeze(out)
out=out.permute(1,2,0)
plt.imshow(out)
```

EDIT:
Here is what this output looked like, this is not the actual output as I lost the weights now but same for all purposes of this question

[image: output]

However if I convert it into a PIL image before displaying it produces weird color patches like shown

```
out=model.forward(x)
out=torch.squeeze(out)
out=transforms.ToPILImage()(out)
plt.imshow(out)
```

[image: Weird patches in pil image]

I'm not using the first method as I have a few other steps after this which require me to have an image with integer values in 0-255.

Comment: What is the `min` and `max` of `out` after the `forward`?

Comment: can you add the output of the first `plt.imshow(out)` where `out` is the raw output before conversion to PIL.Image?

Comment: @Shai I've added the output. Since I lost the weights I can't show the actual output but close to what it looked like(Though a little more blurry like the 2nd image)

Comment: @Berriel they were min : -0.2 max : 1 approx for this image. Could it be the negative values causing the problem? Maybe doing plt.imshow directly clips the negative values to 0 and converting to PIL Image scales the values to 0-255 and that causes the patches.

Comment: @KousikRajesh definitely. ToPILImage does `*255.byte()` which will cause an underflow for the negative values, which will likely generate these artifacts. `plt.show` usually re-scales the range to 0-1.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll fix it, the negative values wouldn't have appeared if I had used relu after the last layer. Thanks a lot for the help!